# Why Apache dont activate Saxon/C extension?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, saxon, php-extension, saxon-c

i have installed Saxon/C extension step by step, by this documentation: `http://zf4.biz/blog/installing-the-saxon-c-php-extension`

I must install it for PHP5, so this documentation was great. It all works fine and if i use this "php -m | grep saxon -i" command they shows me the extension:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'Saxon/C' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Saxon/C
```

But in the phpinfo(); the extension is not listet on.

Anybody know why this dont works?

Comment: Just checking, this blog entry seems to be 3 years old, have you followed the current documentation at http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml ? Installation problems tend to be tricky and require interaction to solve, which doesn't suit the SO model too well, so opening a tracker at saxonica.plan.io may be the best way forward.

Comment: And this works to for php5? I have tried much documentation, but it dont works

Comment: Yes, the instructions cover both PHP5 and PHP7. O'Neil is the expert and he's OOO today (just back from a US trip) but I've alerted him to the post.

Comment: Okay, thank you, i wann try this!

Comment: now i get this error, after the 'make' command: Makefile:194: recipe for target 'php5_saxon.lo' failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug issue is related to the issue [#4151](https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4151). The call to the method getUnderlyingValue() should take not arguments

On line 836 of the file php5_saxon.cpp please replace:

> obj = ooth->xdmNode->getUnderlyingValue(NULL);

With the following:

> obj = ooth->xdmNode->getUnderlyingValue();

Alternatively you can download the following file which contains the fix:

[php5_saxon.cpp](https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.8/hec/Saxon.C.API/php5_saxon.cpp)

You should then be able to build the Saxon/c extension for PHP5. Installation instructions given here http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/index.html

Comment: I have replaced this line and maked the phpize and configure again, but it stills shows the error. Must i make some more to?

Comment: When you run the command phpize. Do you get the following?:
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:             20121113
Zend M/odule Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212

Comment: I got this: Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. Your phpize is set for PHP7. Have you got PHP5 installed on your linux machine? Do you have the phpize5 command available?

Comment: The "problem" i think is, we have 3 or 4 php versions installed, but the apache use the 5.6, the phpize5 command dont work

Comment: I think you can install phpize5. If this is not possible if you are using a 64-bit version of ubuntu I have built the PHP5 library which you can use. See: https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.8/hec/php-library-module/php5/64-bit/HEC/saxon.so

Comment: Yes, now i have change it but now i get this error :/ "checking build system type... Invalid configuration `–enable-saxon': machine `–enable' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub –enable-saxon failed"

Comment: And if i make the "make" command, the same error shows me like yesterday. Is it possible to make this manually? i think the make command only add the extension to the folder or?

Comment: It looks like the issue is relating to the installation of PHP5 on your machine. or there maybe files around from the PHP7 build process. Maybe try calling 'sudo make clean' first. As a work-around please try using the built Saxon/C library I posted as a link. Therefore avoiding the building process.

Comment: I dont now if this is possible, our server is running and our website is online, i dont know what they do with the php configs and the other stuff and they dont know it to, but we need to install saxon, for the new website, i think its better if we use directly the Version for php 7 or? I wanna try to install php new

Comment: I was not suggesting installing the saxon/c on the live site, but in a test environment first.

Comment: If you can move forward to PHP7 I would recommend that. But you mentioned that you need Saxon/C for PHP5, is that still the case?

Comment: On a test environment Saxon/C works, but this is on php7 and we dont know that the old developers had installed 4 versions of php and used for typo3 php5.6 now we dont want to use typo3, we have maded our litle own CMS and for that we need xslt 2.0, that is why we use saxon/c, the php version dont matter, it can be 7 or 5. Now i have deleted php7, and saxon/c, i install it new.

Comment: What version of PHP is your live site running?

Comment: at 5.6 the live site is runnig

Comment: Ok so therefore you could try copying the Saxon/C library which I built for PHP5. All you will need to do is restart apache2 server. But before you do that setup a test environment with PHP5 and install Saxon/C there and when you are happy with the results install it to the live site.

Comment: But what you mean with "all you will need to do is restart the apache2 server" you mean if i only copy the php5 saxon libary from you?

Comment: We have now installed it on php7 and all works. Thanks for the help!